# Run Wireshark without setuid OR capabilities

Tags: sudo, wireshark, root

I want to run Wireshark so that I will have to type in my sudo password to run it, but I don't want to give the dumpcap binary special privileges (set-uid, capabilities, etc.). How can I do that without running Wireshark itself as root?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a script that requires admin privileges to run, but which runs Wireshark without the elevation.  If you use AutoIt for creating the script, demanding administrator's credentials in the script is very easy: Put `#RequireAdmin` at the top of the script.  You would probably then need to `RunAs...` a non-admin, otherwise Wireshark would inherit the elevation.

If this is a security issue, though, this isn't what you want unless you modify the user privileges of Wireshark.exe because somebody could still navigate to the Wireshark directory and run the executable directly.